# How to fix "You are not allowed to perform this action"

Tags: xubuntu

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04

Xubuntu stops me from doing certain things like software updater or installing things through software manager. However, I can still do things through terminal. For example: If I navigate to the system menu, then click on Software Updater, it will pop up, do nothing, then tell me I can't do it. But if I were to open it through terminal it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I do everything through the terminal, but if I recall correctly, there's some program (possibly `gksu` or `gksudo`; there may be a different one for xubuntu) which will prompt for your password when you try to do things which require root via the gui. Check if you have those installed.